# Rooted Xperia Z2 won't read memory card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, sony-xperia-z2

Yesterday I connected my phone in mass storage mode to copy photos off the external microSD card and ejected it properly from Windows before disconnecting it. After that it said there was an error on my memory card.
Now if I go to storage, it reports that the card exists and is mounted, but cannot read from it (and so does not display the usage breakup of apps and media the way it does for internal storage)

If I try using ES File Explorer, it too reports that the memory card exists as well as the count of songs and photos, but cannot read any of them. I have only a couple of apps that I had moved to SD card - these show up in the drawer but either fail with an error or cause the phone to freeze.
I am able to view the contents of the memory card if it's connected to Windows in MTP mode, but again cannot read or copy files.
What's going on?

Is there a fix that doesn't involve reformatting the card and losing everything on it?

**Edit** Just put it into a card reader, and it works normally. I'm able to view and open files.

Comment: did you try accessing sd card from another device
?

Comment: Not yet, plan to use a card reader when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, completely weird, but just taking it out, viewing it with a memory card reader and putting it back did the trick.
Glad I didn't have to erase or format it. I'd like to know what went wrong originally though.